# how to get id of current user in websocket open method?

Tags: java, websocket, shiro

I am trying to get user id in open method of websocket, and for this I am using shiro, but I get null for Subject,Here is my method:

```
@OnOpen
public void open(final Session session, @PathParam("room") final String room) {
    Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
    long id = currentUser.getPrincipals().oneByType(model.Users.class)
            .getId();

    log.info("session openend and bound to room: " + room);
    session.getUserProperties().put("user", id);

}
```

Does anybody have any idea what I should do?

Comment: I'm not familiar with shiro, BUT I'm betting that `currentUser.getPrincipals...` stuff is expecting this to be a normal http request that has cookies and whatnot. You may need to pass an identifier in through the websocket connection to identify your user. Kna mean?

Comment: Thank's I think you are right, I have to think of something for that

Comment: Sounds good. Let me know what you find. Wish I could be more help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a day I solved it, I changed class of open method to this:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/chat/{room}", configurator = GetHttpSessionConfigurator.class, encoders = ChatMessageEncoder.class, decoders = ChatMessageDecoder.class) 
public class ChatEndpoint {

private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

@OnOpen
public void open(final Session session,
        @PathParam("room") final String room, EndpointConfig config) {

    log.info("session openend and bound to room: " + room);

    Principal userPrincipal = (Principal) config.getUserProperties().get(
            "UserPrincipal");
    String user=null;
    try {
         user = (String) userPrincipal.getName();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    session.getUserProperties().put("user", user);
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!! "+user);

}}
```

and GetHttpSessionConfigurator class:

```
public class GetHttpSessionConfigurator extends
    ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {


@Override
public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig config,
        HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response) {
    config.getUserProperties().put("UserPrincipal",request.getUserPrincipal());
    config.getUserProperties().put("userInRole", request.isUserInRole("someRole"));  
}}
```

and Implement my user model from Principal and override getName() method to get id:

```
@Override
public String getName() {
    String id=Long.toString(getId());
    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution could be to use javax.websocket.Session.getUserPrincipal() which **Returns the authenticated user for this Session or null if no user is authenticated for this session** Like so,

```
@OnOpen
public void open(final Session session, @PathParam("room") final String room) {
    Principal userPrincipal = session.getUserPrincipal();
    if (userPrincipal == null) {
        log.info("The user is not logged in.");
    } else {
        String user = userPrincipal.getName();
        // now that your have your user here, your can do whatever other operation you want.
    }
}
```

Subsequent methods like onMessage can also use the same method to retrieve the user.

Comment: For me, it returns null, even though the user that emits the socket request is already authenticated.